# Hibernate 3.6.10 NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I'm having the following issue with my hibernate 3.6.10 project:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [db.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z

Reading some of the issues here on stack overflow, it said I was using the wrong persistence API. So I downloaded the matching hibernate (I've been using the Spring deployment) and copied out the hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar which comes with the hibernate distrib, only to get the self-same message.

Is this telling me that OneToMany is not supported by Hibernate 3.6.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tells your that you have a JPA 1.0 API jar somewhere in your classpath. Such a problem cannot be reliably solved by adding proper JPA 2.0 jar to the classpath, you need to find and remove the offending jar before.

Comment: It appears that I had javaee.jar in my path which has the persistence stuff in it. I deleted it and then was missing the transaction stuff, so I went back to the hibernate libarary and copied in the jta stuff and appear to be past that problem now. Thanks for your help.